# Rails Testing: Failing "Create" specs with deadlocked controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, rspec-rails

I have controllers - Survey, Questions and Options. 
I cannot save Survey without creating Questions first. And in turn Questions cannot be created  creating Options first. How to get "create" specs pass for Survey controller...
Surveys_Controller_spec.rb

```
describe "POST 'create'" do
before(:each) do
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:activated_user)
  login_user(@user)
end

context "with valid parameters" do      
  let(:parameters) { { :title => "Title of the Survey", :description => "description", :activated      => "false", :participant_info => "0", :is_draft => "true",  :thank_you_message => "Thank You", :user_id => @user.id } }

  it "creates a new survey" do
    expect { post :create, :survey => parameters }.to change(Survey, :count).by(1)
  end
```

Surveys_Controller.rb

```
def create
  @survey = convert_enums(current_user.surveys.new(params[:survey]), params)
  respond_to do |format|
  if @survey.save
    format.html { redirect_to dashboard_path, :notice => "Survey was successfully created!"}
  else
    format.html { render :new }
  end
 end
```

Comment: what can I do to build questions for the Survey I am going to create.     I used : after(:build) {|survey| survey.questions << FactoryGirl.build(:mcq_question, survey: survey)} but ends up in ERROR!!